# How to count occurrence of multiple sub-string in a long string with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

I am a fresh with JavaScript. I just tried a lot, but did not get the answer and information to show how to count occurrence of multiple sub-string in a long string at one time.

Further information: I need get the occurrence of these sub-string and if the number of their occurrence to much, I need replace them at one time,so I need get the occurrence at one time.

Here is an example:
The long string Text as below,

> Super Bowl 50 was an American football game to determine the champion of the National Football League (NFL) for the 2015 season. The American Football Conference (AFC) champion Denver Broncos defeated the National Football Conference (NFC) champion Carolina Panthers 24–10 to earn their third Super Bowl title. The game was played on February 7, 2016, at Levi's Stadium in the San Francisco Bay Area at Santa Clara, California. As this was the 50th Super Bowl, the league emphasized the "golden anniversary" with various gold-themed initiatives, as well as temporarily suspending the tradition of naming each Super Bowl game with Roman numerals (under which the game would have been known as "Super Bowl L"), so that the logo could prominently feature the Arabic numerals 50.

The sub-string is a question, but what I need is to count each word occurrence in this sub-string at one time. for example, the word "name","NFL","championship","game" and "is","the" in this string.

> What is the name of NFL championship game?

One of problems is some sub-string is not in the text, and some have shown many times.(which I might replaced it)

The Code I have tried as below, it is wrong, I have tried many different ways but no good results.

```
$(".showMoreFeatures").click(function(){
            var text= $(".article p").text(); // This is to get the text.

            var textCount = new Array();    
// Because I use match, so for the first word "what", will return null, so 
this is to avoid this null. and I was plan to get the count number, if it is 
more than 7 or even more, I will replace them.

            var qus = item2.question;  //This is to get the sub-string
            var checkQus = qus.split(" "); // I split the question to words

            var newCheckQus = new Array(); 
// This is the array I was plan put the sub-string which count number less than 7, which I really needed words.

            var count = new Array();
// Because it is a question as sub-string and have many words, so I wan plan to get their number and put them in a array. 


            for(var k =0; k < checkQus.length; k++){
                    textCount = text.match(checkQus[k],"g")
                    if(textCount == null){
                        continue;
                    }
                    for(var j =0; j<checkQus.length;j++){
                        count[j] = textCount.length;
                    }
                    //count++;
            }
```

I was tried many different ways, and searched a lot, but no good results. The above code just want to show what I have tried and my thinking(might totally wrong). But actually it is not working , if you know how to implement it,solve my problem, please just tell me, no need to correct my code.

Thanks very much.

Comment: This doesn't make too much sense - I am wondering if they just want you to count the occurrences of the words "Super Bowl"?  That is the name of the NFL Championship Game, after all.  Just a thought because it doesn't seem like there is any way to count that string that you have. Counting "Super Bowl" seems like a more logical exercise?

Comment: I am not a naive English speaker, sorry that might I didn't clear it. The final effect what I need is to replace(change to other color) all the words in question in the text where the word is. so it is running words by words,which word in the question, because this is one of questions as example, actually,I have many different question and their length is different.   To be specific, I need change color to  "super" in text, and "bowl", and "NFL", and others.  but "is" and "the" is not necessary, So my thought is to count the occurrence of the question word. Am I clear?

Comment: Finally, I need get these word's occurrence, and might use if condition, if  the count < 5, then run replace(txt1/g, txt2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood the question correctly then it seems you need to count the number of times the words in the question (`que`) appear in the text (`txt`)...

```
var txt = "Super Bowl 50 was an American ...etc... Arabic numerals 50.";
var que = "What is the name of NFL championship game?";
```

I'll go through this in vanilla JavaScript and you can transpose it for JQuery as required.

First of all, to focus on the text we can make things a little simpler by changing the strings to lowercase and removing some of the punctuation.

```
// both strings to lowercase
txt = txt.toLowerCase();
que = que.toLowerCase();

// remove punctuation
// using double \\ for proper regular expression syntax
var puncArray = ["\\,", "\\.", "\\(", "\\)", "\\!", "\\?"];

puncArray.forEach(function(P) {
    // create a regular expresion from each punctuation 'P'
    var rEx = new RegExp( P, "g");

    // replace every 'P' with empty string (nothing)
    txt = txt.replace(rEx, '');
    que = que.replace(rEx, ''); 
});
```

Now we can create a cleaner array from `str` and `que` as well as a hash table from `que` like so...

```
// Arrays: split at every space
var txtArray = txt.split(" ");
var queArray = que.split(" ");

// Object, for storing 'que' counts
var queObject = {};

queArray.forEach(function(S) {
    // create 'queObject' keys from 'queArray'
    // and set value to zero (0)
    queObject[S] = 0;
});
```

`queObject` will be used to hold the words counted.  If you were to `console.debug(queObject)` at this point it would look something like this...

```
console.debug(queObject);
/* =>
queObject = {
    what: 0,
    is: 0,
    the: 0,
    name: 0,
    of: 0,
    nfl: 0,
    championship: 0,
    game: 0
}
*/
```

Now we want to test each element in `txtArray` to see if it contains any of the elements in `queArray`.  If the test is `true` we'll add +1 to the equivalent `queObject` property, like this...

```
// go through each element in 'queArray'
queArray.forEach(function(A) {
    // create regular expression for testing
    var rEx = new RegExp( A );

    // test 'rEx' against elements in 'txtArray'
    txtArray.forEach(function(B) {
        // is 'A' in 'B'?
        if (rEx.test(B)) {
            // increase 'queObject' property 'A' by 1.
            queObject[A]++;
        }
    });
});
```

We use RegExp `test` method here rather than String `match` method because we just want to know if "is A in B == true".  If it is true then we increase the corresponding `queObject` property by 1.  This method will also find words inside words, such as 'is' in 'San Franc**is**co' etc.

All being well, logging `queObject` to the console will show you how many times each word in the question appeared in the text.

```
console.debug(queObject);
/* =>
queObject = {
    what: 0
    is: 2
    the: 17
    name: 0
    of: 2
    nfl: 1
    championship: 0
    game: 4
}
*/
```

Hoped that helped. :)

See MDN for more information on:

- [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- [RegExp.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Comment: Thanks very much, and this is exactly what I want and I need. Thanks very very much~~

Comment: I have tried your way for many times in my code, but still get some detail problems, So I change to another way to implement my final achievement . Because I just want to excluded some useless words in question, so I built a new array to store these useless word which is obvious, and just excluded them.  Anyway ,Thanks very much, and I have learned many~

Comment: @CindyL : You're welcome.  Glad to help - that's what we are here for.  Don't forget to 'Accept' the answers that answer your questions. :)

Comment: Thanks remind， I am also fresh here, I don't know about this accept part before, Thanks~